# JQuery AutoComplete always displays Ordered list?

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use **Jquery autocomplete** and yes, Indeed was able to succeed. But, stuck up at this point:

The jquery auto complete fetches the `json` data, but displays it in a `bulleted list`.

I tried to modify the `jquery.ui.autocomplete.css`.

But still then, it contains,

```
.ui-menu {
 list-style:none;
 padding: 2px;
 margin: 0;
 display:block;
 float: left;
}
```

Note that the list-style is none, but still why a bulleted list is displayed to me ?

(I am currently using MVC 4 default template which comes with visual studio 2012)

Comment: Is the jquery stylesheet linked before or after the main stylesheet?

Comment: @Romoku: sorry if this is silly, but how do you check that?

Comment: In reference to what @Romoku said, you could override the jQueryUI css by changing it to `list-style:none !important;`

Comment: Yeah that's the solution. The `list-style:none;` will get overridden by the main stylesheet.

Comment: What is `list`?  That's not a tag that I'm familiar with.  Should that not be `.ui-menu`?

Comment: @Archer: Yup, you are right. It works like as you guys suggested. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end.  Just a word of advice, don't edit the css files that come with libraries/plugins in case they ever get updated and you need to overwrite them with new files.  Override in your own css file, like you did in this case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a snippet to your own css file (e.g. `main.css`)

```
.ui-menu {
    list-style: none !important;
}
```

This will force the jquery class style to take precedence.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEPnF/2/)